# Apply function across rows over a subset in R

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, subset

Apologize in advance because I'm sure the question has been asked before but I'm looking for an efficient way to do this preferably with the data table package.

I have a matrix, which could be a data table if it can be done using the package, with data that I need to group by columns but apply a `mean` function across the rows for each group of columns. The end result should be a matrix (or data table) that contains columns with values that are averaged based on the group.

```
set.seed(123)
testMatrix <- matrix(nrow = 15, ncol = 10)
for (i in 1:nrow(testMatrix)) {
    testMatrix[i,] <- runif(1) 
}
```

I know the values are all the same but that's not important for this. So now I need to find the average across the rows but for each pair of columns. So the end result should be a data table with 5 columns and 15 rows, with the average of all the rows between V1, V2 and V3, V4, etc. Column 1 will have 15 values that is the average between all the rows of the first two columns and so on.The method is going to be incorporated in a loop to automate over 100s of data sets, that's way efficiency is important.

Comment: This is pretty efficient `(df1[c(F,T)] + df1[c(T,F)])/2` idea comes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026944/how-to-calculate-means-across-rows-of-three-multi-column-dataframes

Comment: If you want to work with a matrix, this question covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36432686

Comment: The method works with matrices too `(testMatrix[,c(F,T)] + testMatrix[,c(T,F)]) / 2`

Comment: But if I'm applying across multiple columns, say more than two, then I would have to write it out for each column? So the data set I have is actually 35 columns and I need to group by 7. Would it be `(df1[c(F,T)] + df1[c(T,F)]) + df1[c(F,T)] + etc/7`? @PierreLafortune

Comment: Isn't there a way using `rowMeans` or something within `data.table`? I've heard of the `cut` function but never used it. @PierreLafortune

Comment: I reopened the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the data by group and find the row means of each.

```
#Split using integer division and a generic level generator
grps <- split(1:ncol(df), gl(ncol(df) %/% 7, 7))

#Find mean of each grouped row
sapply(grps, function(ind) rowMeans(df[,ind]))
#              1         2         3         4         5
# [1,]  45.71143  45.71143  45.71143  45.71143  45.71143
# [2,]  45.82786  45.82786  45.82786  45.82786  45.82786
# [3,]  36.08286  36.08286  36.08286  36.08286  36.08286
# [4,]  60.16214  60.16214  60.16214  60.16214  60.16214
# [5,]  83.61571  83.61571  83.61571  83.61571  83.61571
# [6,]  54.36286  54.36286  54.36286  54.36286  54.36286
# [7,]  92.84571  92.84571  92.84571  92.84571  92.84571
```